# How to add an item of type T to a List<T> without knowing what T is?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, .net-4.0

I'm handling an event which passes event args pointing to a List and a T newitem, and my job is to add the newitem to the List.

How can I do this without checking for all the types I know T might be?

The current code is a couple dozen lines of this:

```
private void DataGridCollectionViewSource_CommittingNewItem(object sender, DataGridCommittingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
  Type t = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection.GetType();

  if (t == typeof(List<Person>))
  {
    List<Person> source = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection as List<Person>;
    source.Add(e.Item as Person);
  }
  else if (t == typeof(List<Place>))
  {
    List<Place> source = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection as List<Place>;
    source.Add(e.Item as Place);
  }
  ...
```

I'd prefer if it were possible to do something like this:

```
((List<T>) e.CollectionView.SourceCollection).Add((T)e.Item);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply don't  use generics here:

```
IList source = (IList)e.CollectionView.SourceCollection;
source.Add(e.Item);
```

You could also use `ICollection` in place of `IList`.

Comment: 'System.Collections.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' - which is why I posted this initially, but I hadn't tried IList, that one works. Thanks.

Comment: @Alain ah, fair enough - I lost track of which methods are in which interface (iirc it is slightly different between the non-generic and generic versions)

Comment: As a sanity check, is there a way that I can verify that the SourceCollection is of the same type as e.Item?

Comment: @Alain only by using reflection. However, any list-of-T etc will throw an exception if it is wrong, which is easy to spot

Comment: @Alain you could test whether the source collection implements the generic `IList<>`, and, if it does, get the type argument, and then check whether `typeArg.IsAssignableFrom(e.Item.GetType())`.  Note that this is a better approach than checking type equality, because, of course, `e.Item` might be an `Antelope` while the collection might implement `IList<Animal>`.

Comment: @phoog that's fine, but would work best from a generic method. In a non-generic method tht is adding an awful lot of code just to reproduce wht already exists in all standrd generic collection implementations for free (I.e. type-checking when using the non-generic API). As a general rule, if you find yourself using masses of reflection in a generic method, it is worth looking for a on-generic implementation

Comment: @MarcGravell agreed.  Checking the types with reflection would be overkill here, unless the OP has some course of action in mind *other than throwing an exception.*  If an exception would be the proper response to incompatibility, however, especially since the object that owns both the `CollectionView` and the `Item` presumably guarantees that they're compatible, it makes more sense just to let the non-generic `IList.Add(object)` method throw the exception.

Answer (score 4):

Since generic collections implement object-based interfaces defined in the `System.Collections` namespace, you can do this:

```
((System.Collections.IList) e.CollectionView.SourceCollection).Add(e.Item);
```

Of course the type checking is now shifted to runtime, so you need to make sure that `e.Item` would be of the correct type, because the compiler cannot check it after the cast.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a specific typed class?

```
public class MyClass<ABC>
    {
        private void DataGridCollectionViewSource_CommittingNewItem(
              object sender, DataGridCommittingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Type t = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection.GetType();

        if (t == typeof(List<ABC>))
        {
            List<ABC> source = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection as List<ABC>;
            source.Add(e.Item as ABC);
        }
    }
}
```

or not depending on the context of what your trying to do....

Answer (score 1):

```
void AddItem<T>(IEnumerable sourceCollection, object item)
{
     ((List<T>)sourceCollectio).Add((T)item); 
}
```

Then

```
Type t = e.CollectionView.SourceCollection.GetType(); 
if (t == typeof(List<Person>)) { 
    AddItem<Person>(e.CollectionView.SourceCollection, e.Item);
} else if (t == typeof(List<Place>)) { 
    AddItem<Place>(e.CollectionView.SourceCollection, e.Item);
}
```